# Rails. How display "N/A" for nil record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, crud, null

So I allow nil values on some methods of a model. However when I display a record in index action and the loop goes through all records it shows nil values as "", however I would prefer something like, "N/A" or "Hasn't been entered yet"

Is there to_s for Nil:Nilclass method that does it? Or is it set somewhere else?

Comment: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/NilClass.html#method-i-to_s

Seems that answers my question

Comment: However the question still remains the same how do we override that method? Is there any safe way to do? Any quidance

Comment: The thing is: you probably shouldn't override it. It will most likely result in severe problems with standard ruby functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your application helper

```
def format_value(value)
  value ||= 'N/A'
end
```

And in your view call that method like

```
<%= format_value(@user.name)%>
```

Answer (score 2):

Assume that you are checking nil against `user.name` and if you would like to do it in the view without writing any helpers, you can do it like this

```
<%= @user.name.nil? ? "N/A" : @user.name %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer making use of helpers here. Define a method in the respective helper of that view and call this method from the view.

```
module YourHelperClass
 def format_nil_values(value)
   unless value
     "N/A"
   end
 end
end
```